# Thread Breakpoint at Object Initialization Swift

Tags: multithreading, object, initialization, swift, breakpoints

I have a simple class, but whenever some other part of my code tries to initialize a Movie instance, it says `Thread 1: breakpoint 5.1` at the closing brace of `init`.  I see no reason why this should be happening.  Anyone have an idea?

Note:  There are about 30 other properties, but I removed them from the code for the sake of brevity.

```
class Movie {

var movieID: Int
var movieURL: String
var dateUploaded: String
var dateUploadedEpoch: Int

init(movieID: Int) {
    self.movieID = movieID
    self.movieURL = " "
    self.dateUploaded = " "
    self.dateUploadedEpoch = 0
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: `Thread 1: breakpoint 5.1`.  That's all it gives me.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this SO answer (I had a similar problem, it was a breakpoint from an earlier error that threw me for a loop):

[iOS app breakpoints on running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821587/ios-app-breakpoints-on-running)