# Breakpoint 5.1 while assigning constant to textfield

Tags: xcode, swift

I keep getting a Breakpoint 5.1 error while trying to run my code, keep in mind that this runs perfectly fine in my other applications.

```
@IBAction func doneTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = emailField.text


    if (email?.isEmpty != nil) {
        let emailEmpty:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "It looks like you forgot to provide us with your email address, try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        emailEmpty.show()
    } else {
        var user = PFUser()

        user.email = email

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
                if error.code == 125 {
                    print("Invalid Email Address")
                } else if error.code == 203 {
                    print("Email is already taken")
                }
            } else {
                print("Signup Process Completed.")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? I have written this about 15 times to make sure I did not make some silly mistake but I still cant seem to figure out why it is throwing this error when I run it.

Comment: Remove the breakpoint?

Comment: I am new to programming and have no clue what that means, lol.

Comment: Remove the little blue marker shown at the line of code that it is stopping on.

Comment: Stop writing code and learn what are breakpoints and how to use it to debug if you know nothing about these.

Comment: this was answered. Refer to this [IOS app breakpoints on running]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821587/ios-app-breakpoints-on-running