# Declaring array error in swift2

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, swift2

I have declared a variable called `restaurantNames`  and used an array to store the table data. When I run my program, I get an error   `Thread 1: Break point 1.3` but there's no highlighted errors on my code and also the TableView doesn't show the lines between rows it's just a blank page.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var restaurantNames = ["Lucky WOK", "JFK", "Cafe11"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return the number of rows in the section 

        return restaurantNames.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIndentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIndentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell 

        cell.textLabel?.text = restaurantNames [ indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }
```

[image: Picture]

Output of the console:

```
UIKit-3512.29.5/UITableView.m:6547
2015-12-16 01:37:50.392 Dine-In[35796:238637] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Comment: Even the table view's separators between empty rows are missing. Looks like your table view controller does not have its views set correctly...?

Comment: The "error" message looks like execution is just stopping at one of your break points. Did you try resuming? Or disabling break points?

Comment: See this: [iOS app breakpoints on running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821587/ios-app-breakpoints-on-running) or this: [Xcode + remove all breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665744/xcode-remove-all-breakpoints).

Comment: first check whether you have given the delegate and data source to the table view in the storyboard and in the swift file where you are using the table view.

Comment: now the error moved to the AppDelegate I get `Thread 1: signal SIGBAT` @MartinR

Comment: Setting a breakpoint is not an error, that is something that *you* (deliberately or not) did. – Please update your question with the relevant information: Exact full error message, stack backtrace etc.

Comment: yes I gave a `datasource` & `delegate` to the Table View @ArpitDhamane

Comment: @MartinR I updated the question with the new console output.

Comment: @FrancescStudio your cell is on storybroard?

Comment: Please search for the error message "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard", there are lots of similar questions.

Comment: Thank you for the help @MartinR The problem was I didn't set the identifier of the cell to be the the same as the `Let cellIdentifier` declaration I made.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14939860/377369) will answer your question.